# Grafana PromQL: How do I create a bar chart witch displays one value per day at 13 o'clock

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics, promql

Currently I have a bar chart witch displays the correct value per day.
But I want it to display the value at 13 o'clock. Thats why today is also missing.

My current output:
[image: My current output]

I use `max_over_time(file_counter[1d])` with `Min interval = 1d`.
[image: My current settings]

Only problem is the time of the day.

Any help is appreciated.